# Element.innerHTML breaks connection between element and Document in DOM(isConnected = false)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So basically I was trying to make an error message that is hidden by default be displayed when the user inputs incorrect information. However, the message wasn't appearing. So I used the debugger and found out that the error node element at the top of the js. code was successfully finding the element in the HTML and also successfully changing it's properties. And yet nothing was happening. So after a bit of research I found out that there is a property called isConnected which shows if the Node is connected to the Document. Turns out mine was connected(true) immediately after finding the element, but it was disconnected(false) by the time it entered the errorHandler() func. So again after a bit of debugging I found out that the bottom line of the onPageLoad func was causing the problem. It used to be rootUl.innerHTML += template(countriesObj); but that was breaking it. However, when I moved my error element in the HTML from the ul to outside the id="root" div, it was working fine. It was only breaking when the element was inside the ul. At the end of the day I fixed it by using Element.insertAdjacentHTML() instead, which wouldnt sever the connection between the error element and Document. So after about an hour of struggle, I am curious why that happens and what the difference  is between rootUl.innerHTML += template(countriesObj); and rootUl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template(countriesObj));
Just to add, rootUl.innerHTML+=template(countriesObj) breaks the connection even when used by other function which are not shown here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>List Towns</title>
    <script src="../handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 700; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        Input in the following format: "{Country}: {town}, {town} {Country}: {town}, {town}" and so on. Matching is case-insensitive. Non-english characters are not supported. Numbers are not supported. Check regex for more info. Reset button deletes entire database and refreshes page. 
    </p>
    <form action="#" class="content">
        <label for="towns">Towns</label>
        <input id="towns" type="text" placeholder="ex. Bulgaria: Burgas, Varna Turkey: Ankara"/>
        <button id="btnLoadTowns">Load</button>
    </form>
    <div id="root">
        <ul>
            <!--When the element was here, innerHTML wasn't working correctly-->
            <h4 id="error" style="color: rgb(136, 9, 0); display: none;" >Error. Input string not in correct format. Look at instructions above.</h4>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--When the element was here, innerHTML was working fine-->
    <!-- <h4 id="error" style="color: rgb(136, 9, 0); display: none;" >Error. Input string not in correct format. Look at instructions above.</h4> -->
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <h4 id="empty-database" style="color: rgb(136, 9, 0); display: none;" >Database is currently empty.</h4>
</body>
<script src="./app.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
async function pageApp(){
    //Misc
    let error = document.querySelector('#error');
    let emptyDatabase = document.getElementById('empty-database');
    // Grab the unordered list of countries
    let rootUl = document.querySelector('#root ul');
    // Extract(GET request) data from database
    let database = await getRequestForCountries();
    // Get the two templates: One is for both country and town, another is just for town when country already exists
    let template = await getTemplate();
    let templateTown = await getTemplateTown();
    // Load countries on page load
    onPageLoad();
    //Attach load event to button
    attachLoadEvent();
    //Reset button for deleting the database
    resetButton()

    function errorHandler(){
        error.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function(){
            error.style.color = 'rgb(136, 9, 0)';
            error.style.background = 'none';
        }, 150)
        error.style.color = 'red';
        error.style.background = 'rgb(136, 9, 0)';
    }

    function onPageLoad(){
        database.forEach(entry => {
            let townsArr = entry.towns;
            let countryName = entry.countryName;
            let townsArrObj = townsArr.reduce((acc, cur) =>{
                let townObj = {
                    name: cur
                }
                acc.push(townObj);
                return acc;
            },[]);
            let countriesObj = {
                countries:[
                    {
                        name: countryName, 
                        towns: townsArrObj
                    }
                ]
            }
            //Was rootUl.innerHTML += template(countriesObj); But that breaks the DOM of error and makes error.isConnected = false; 
            // rootUl.innerHTML += template(countriesObj);
            rootUl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template(countriesObj)); 
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Element.innerHTML +=`, gets `HTML` code within the element and append it with something.

```js
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML += `<span>Appended span</span>`;
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum
  <span style="color: red">Something</span>
<p>
```

Whereas, `Element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'To be inserted node')`, will add new node, before the specified element.

```js
document.querySelector('p').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>I am div</div>');
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```